# Collatz SPOJ- python - giving NZEC error

Tags: python

**EDIT: Hey I got the answer . The correct code is written below. As written as the answer, I should have kept the code in a try/except block** 
I am trying to solve the "3n+1" a.k.a Collatz Conjecture problem at the SPOJ site. http://www.spoj.pl/problems/CLTZ/ .  Here is the code I wrote : ***EDIT***

```
import sys,os
#This is for the Collatz Conjecture problem in SPOJ.
while 1:
    try:
        line = sys.stdin.readline()
        n=int(line)
    except:
        break
    #print 'Line=',line

    #n=int(line)
    if(n==1):
        print n
        continue
    else:
        count=0
        while(n!=1):
            if(n%2==0):
                n = n/2
                count=count+1
            else:
                n= 3 * n + 1
                count=count+1
    print count+1
```

I am running into NZEC error. Some test cases that I have tried  are :

```
123123
181
235
128
346
33
234
22
123
47
123
47
123
47
235
128
34
14
325
25
1234
133
123
47
125
109
```

I made the change which takes care of  newline character . It still gives an error :( 
Please let me know where I am going wrong :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At the end of the input, you read an empty line, converting that to `int` raises an exception. Just wrap your code in a `try-except` or `break` from the loop when the read line is empty.

```
while 1:
    line = sys.stdin.readline()
    if line == "":
        break
    n=int(line)
```

If the above doesn't work,

```
while 1:
    try:
        line = sys.stdin.readline()
        n = int(line)
        #other stuff
    except:
        break
```

should get rid of `NZEC`.

But probably you will need to do something better to solve the problem within the time limit, the SPOJ problems rarely allow the naive approach.

Comment: Hey I made a change to handle newline character. It still gives the same NZEC thing :(  I also tried doing if(not line): break . But that also gives the same thing

Answer (score 0):

The best way I have found till now is this

```
import sys
for k in sys.stdin:
k = int(k)
if k==1:
   print k
   #.... rest  of the code
```

Hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

Since languages like C are white space insensitive while taking input, sometimes the test cases in SPOJ contain extra white spaces. Here's a generalized way to take inputs (to avoid NZECs) for SPOJ problems.

```
import sys
tokenizedInput = sys.stdin.read().split()    # Tokenize by white spaces
```

For example, if your input data were something like this -

```
3
2 4
5 6 stfas
abcd
```

tokenizedInput would be ['3', '2', '4', '5', '6', 'stfas', 'abcd']. You can then use this to read the input data.